# How to manuplate path in JSON using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to create a new file inside a file. How can I achieve that?

Below I'm getting the files and their paths and I can access them

```
 <div ng-repeat="t in main.path" style="padding:10px; float:left">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="getFiles(t.path)">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" style="padding-right:10px"></span>{{t.name}}
</button>
</div>
<div ng-repeat=" t in files" style="clear:both">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="t.children==true" ng-click="getFiles('projects/'+t.path)" style="margin:10px">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close" style="padding-right:10px"></span>{{t.name}}</button>
<a href="http://xyz.ngrok.io/{{t.path}}" download class="btn btn-default" role="button" ng-if="t.children==false" style="margin:10px">
    <i class="fas fa-folder">download</i> {{t.name}}</button>
</div>
```

I want to create a new folder in the path which I clicked. How can I do that ?

```
 <form ng-submit="createFolder('projects/'+files.path)">
 <div class="modal fade" id="createFolderModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Create Folder</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="text" name="directory" ng-model="createfolder">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button  type="submit"  class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Below is my controller

```
   angular.module('filesController', [])
  .controller('filesCtrl', function (User, $scope, $http) {
$scope.getFiles = function (path) {
  var Obj = {
    path: path,
  }
  console.log(Obj);
  $http.post('http://xyz/api/file/path', Obj).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    $scope.files = result.data.project;
  });
}

$scope.createFolder = function (path) {
  var create = {
    createfolder: $scope.createfolder,
    path: path,
  }
  console.log(create);
  /*$http.post('http://xyz/api/createfolder', create).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
    $scope.files = result.data.project;
  });*/
}
```